# Regex to show the number of class declarations?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, documentation, visual-studio-2022

I want to count the number of structs/classes declarations (not forward declarations) for documentation purposes. I always did this manually but now I have >70 classes, So I'm thinking about using regex.

Possible declarations are

```cpp
class Foo
{
   //...
}

class Foo : public Bar
{
}

template<typename T>
class Foo<T> : public Bar<T>
{
}

class MACRO Foo : public Bar
{
}

class MACRO Foo final : public Bar
{
}
```

But these should not match

```cpp
class Foo;
void Func(class Foo* foo, class Bar* bar)
{
}
```

So far I have this

```
(?:class|struct) .+\n{
```

But it matches for

```cpp
void Func(class Foo* foo, class Bar* bar)
{
}
```

I think If I could somehow tell this regex to not match `)` in `.+` it would work for all my cases.

`(?:class|struct) .+\n{`

Edit:

This helped with my problem, it does not include or exclude all possible cases but works with my current coding style.

`(?:^[^\S\r\n]*struct|class) .+\n\s*{`

Comment: for documentation purposes you can use doxygen. I suppose its very much simpler to count the number of class definitions in doxygens output rather than in the code directly

Comment: *"the number of structs/classes declarations (not forward declarations)"* -- in other words, the number of `struct`/`class` *definitions*.